# OpenGL ES: Need OpenGL ES (1.x and 2.0) API list

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have some background on OpenGL (Desktop Version). Now, I'm planning to move to OpenGL ES. For this, I need to know the following:

- what is the corresponding API that i used in OpenGL need to be used in OpenGL ES (1.1 or 2.0).
- List of APIs available in OpenGL ES 1.1 and OpenGL ES 2.0.

This question may be an very open question. But, I could'nt get any clear API list through search in different sites. Atleast for OpenGL ES 2.0, I could find a spec file that is available in [OpenGL ES 2.0 Reference Card](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/reference_cards/OpenGL-ES-2_0-Reference-card.pdf). But I couldn't find any more details.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the [OpenGL ES 2.0 Reference Pages](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/) and [OpenGL ES 1.1 Reference Pages](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/), which contain the information you want (plus the API documentation).

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES 1.1 is approximately OpenGL 1.5
OpenGL ES 2.0 is approximately OpenGL 2.0
That's written even in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES

Of course many features of desktop GL are not present in ES API.

Here are the official specs of ES and other useful information: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/